# What are some computers that support NUMA?

Tags: numa

What are some computers that support NUMA? Also, how many cores are required? I have tried searching in Google and Bing but couldn't find any answers.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general hardware tech support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NUMA Support
    The traditional model for multiprocessor support is symmetric multiprocessor (SMP). In this model, each processor has equal access to memory and I/O. As more processors are added, the processor bus becomes a limitation for system performance.
    System designers use non-uniform memory access (NUMA) to increase processor speed without increasing the load on the processor bus. The architecture is non-uniform because each processor is close to some parts of memory and farther from other parts of memory. The processor quickly gains access to the memory it is close to, while it can take longer to gain access to memory that is farther away.
    In a NUMA system, CPUs are arranged in smaller systems called nodes. Each node has its own processors and memory, and is connected to the larger system through a cache-coherent interconnect bus.
    The system attempts to improve performance by scheduling threads on processors that are in the same node as the memory being used. It attempts to satisfy memory-allocation requests from within the node, but will allocate memory from other nodes if necessary. It also provides an API to make the topology of the system available to applications. You can improve the performance of your applications by using the NUMA functions to optimize scheduling and memory usage.
************************************************************************    
    Multiple Processors
    Computers with multiple processors are typically designed for one of two architectures: non-uniform memory access (NUMA) or symmetric multiprocessing (SMP).
    In a NUMA computer, each processor is closer to some parts of memory than others, making memory access faster for some parts of memory than other parts. Under the NUMA model, the system attempts to schedule threads on processors that are close to the memory being used. For more information about NUMA, see NUMA Support.
    In an SMP computer, two or more identical processors or cores connect to a single shared main memory. Under the SMP model, any thread can be assigned to any processor. Therefore, scheduling threads on an SMP computer is similar to scheduling threads on a computer with a single processor. However, the scheduler has a pool of processors, so that it can schedule threads to run concurrently. Scheduling is still determined by thread priority, but it can be influenced by setting thread affinity and thread ideal processor, as discussed in this topic.
```